# tvos AVPlayerViewController how to display subtitles tab on swipedown menu

Tags: objective-c, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

In `tvOS`, in the menu that is being displayed when a user swipes down on the remote, that shows "subtitles, audio & info" on other movie apps, how to create another tab with buttons?

Below is my code:

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *titleMetadataItem = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
titleMetadataItem.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
titleMetadataItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle;
titleMetadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
titleMetadataItem.value = @"The Title";

NSArray *externalMetadata = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleMetadataItem, nil];

_player.player.currentItem.externalMetadata = externalMetadata;
```

Can someone please tell me how  can I create a buttons in the swipe down menu of an `AVPlayerViewController` so that a user can toggle between turning off or turning on the subtitles? I do not have the `srt files` embedded in the video. Instead I have a separate `subtitle parser` and I display it on a label. I was able to get info section to show with text but is there any way to add buttons?

OR
how I can add a subtitle option to the video?
This does not work:
  `_player.requiresFullSubtitles = YES;`

Thanks!

Comment: Jenel. Did you get any solution to this problem? Can you tell me how to resolve that? Actually, I want to add a custom button to place of the subtitle.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you have to create a custom view that contains the button  and just toggle when you want that button to show.

Answer (score 2):

The `AVPlayerViewController` only loads subtitles if they're embedded in the HLS streams, and that is also the only legal way to show the **"Subtitles"** tab on the swipe down menu.

I built a utility for dynamically adding **VTT** subtitles to **HLS** (m3u8) streams called `ACHLSCaptioningServer` (https://github.com/acotilla91/ACHLSCaptioningServer).

**Note:** If you only have access to SRT files you'll need to find a way to convert SRTs to VTTs.

**How to use:**

```
NSURL *origStreamURL = your_original_stream-url;
NSURL *vttFileURL = your_vtt_file_url;

NSURL *streamURL = [[ACHLSCaptioningServer sharedInstance] getCaptionedHLSStreamFromStream:origStreamURL vttURL:vttFileURL];

//
// play stream
//

AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:streamURL options:nil];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:videoAsset];

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

AVPlayerViewController *avPlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[avPlayerController setPlayer:player];
[avPlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self addChildViewController:avPlayerController];
[self.view addSubview:avPlayerController.view];
[avPlayerController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: thanks ! do you know any way i could convert the SRT files to VTT?